# How to extract a value from this JSON response

Tags: php, json

I am using the `file_get_contents()` function in PHP to retrieve the contents on a page containing a JSON response. However, I am struggling to get the `"text"` data.

```
$response = file_get_contents(someData)
```

I can use     `var_dump(json_decode($response));` to show the data, however, I am trying to get the data from the `"text"` field only within duration.

So far I have tried

- $response[0];
- $response->rows[0]->elements[0]->duration[0]->text;

But I cannot seem to get the data. I have pasted the response below

```
{
   "destination_addresses" : [ "Manchester, UK", "Liverpool, Merseyside, UK" ],
   "origin_addresses" : [ "London, UK" ],
   "rows" : [
  {
     "elements" : [
        {
           "distance" : {
              "text" : "335 km",
              "value" : 335444
           },
           "duration" : {
              "text" : "3 hours 36 mins",
              "value" : 12955
           },
           "status" : "OK"
        },
        {
           "distance" : {
              "text" : "354 km",
              "value" : 354415
           },
           "duration" : {
              "text" : "3 hours 43 mins",
              "value" : 13387
           },
           "status" : "OK"
        }
     ]
  }
     ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Comment: [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: `duration`, `distance`, etc.. are not arrays. they're objects. `.... ->duration->text`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$response = json_decode(file_get_contents(someData));

$text = $response->rows[0]->elements[0]->duration->text;

var_dump($text);
```

Your only mistake was a `[0]` after `duration`.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Just had to add $response = json_decode(file_get_contents(someData), true);